# .htaccess rewriterule /directory/ to php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with showing images and css files on my site when using RewriteRule on .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/?$ page.php?id=home [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^stats/?$ statspage.php?id=abcd [L,QSA]
```

...but the images and css files not loaded.

Comment: you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RewriteCond` before each `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ page.php?id=home [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^stats/?$ statspage.php?id=abcd [L,QSA]
```

---

`RewriteCond` provides more detailed qualifications for a particular `RewriteRule`.

`%{REQUEST_URI}` is a server variable. It provides the requested URL path, i.e, the portion after the domain name, but not including the query string.

The condition I added to your rules allows all URLs that end in the listed extensions to skip that particular rewrite. Which means Apache can send the resource as it is requested.

The exclamation mark `!` means NOT.

Periods have a special meaning in regular expressions so if you want to match an actual period they need to be escaped with a backslash: `\.`.

The combination of parenthesis: `()` and pipes: `|` create alternating lists: `(gif|jpe?g|png|css)`. So here any extension will match: `gif` OR `jpeg` OR `jpg` OR `png` OR `css`. The question mark after the `e` in `jpe?g` makes the `e` optional, hence `jpeg` OR `jpg`.

The dollar sign `$` means "end of string", so the matched pattern must be the last thing in the URL path.

In English: Apache mod_rewrite is instructed to match URL paths that do NOT end in a period followed by either "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", or "css". Therefore URLs that do match (images and css) skip the rule.